# Using SQLAlchemy relationships while avoiding circular dependency with imports

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy, relationship

I am having a problem using db.relationships. I noticed that to use relationships in my queries, each models that references another through a relationship has to be aware of that model (through imports as in my example below). All my models are in separate files, so I am afraid I will face circular dependency issues. Can any suggest to me how to overcome this constraints.

from .models.role import Role

```
class User(db.Model, BaseModel):
    __tablename__ = 'user'

    id = db.Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, nullable=False)
    first_name = db.Column(String(255), nullable=False)
    last_name = db.Column(String(255), nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(String(255), nullable=False)
    role_id = db.Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), db.ForeignKey('role.id'), nullable=False)
    
    role = db.relationship("Role", back_populates="user")
    

from .models.user import User

class Role(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'role'

    id = db.Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, nullable=False)
    name = db.Column(String(60), nullable=False)
    description = db.Column(String(255), nullable=True)

    users = db.relationship('User', back_populates='role')
```

Comment: Since you specify the other class by a string name, you don't need to import the class you are referencing.  Just try your code without the import statements.

Comment: I tried that implementation, and ran into this error:

sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: One or more mappers failed to initialize - can't proceed with initialization of other mappers. Triggering mapper: 'Mapper[User(user)]'. Original exception was: Mapper 'Mapper[Role(role)]' has no property 'user'.  If this property was indicated from other mappers or configure events, ensure registry.configure() has been called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my Role class, I had defined a users relationship, but I was referring to it as user in the back_populates of the User class. I have fixed the mismatch. Here's the correct definition.

```
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user'

    id = db.Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, nullable=False)
    name = db.Column(String(255), nullable=False)
    role_id = db.Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), db.ForeignKey('role.id'), nullable=False)
    role = db.relationship('Role', back_populates='users')

    def serialize(self):
        return {
            'name': self.name
        }
```